# telerik grid + nhibernate + IEnumerable

Tags: nhibernate, telerik

This is related to:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764297/sortable-telerik-grid-nhibernate-iqueryable-and-asp-net-mvc)

The telerik grid makes it very easy to implement paging, filtering etc. using just something like this in a repository:

```
public IEnumerable<Organism> GetBlas()
{
    return Session.Query<Bla>();
}
```

I am just wondering whether this would also work if I map things to a view model and return IEnumerable using for example:

```
SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(BlaViewModel)))
```

and before that HQL, ICriteria or even (?) createsql?

Thanks!

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work.

ToString will be called on the properties of Bla.