# Telerik MVC Grid Grouping with nHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, nhibernate, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have an MVC3 with nHibernate project, and I would like to make use of the Telerik MVC Extensions Grid.  The grid must perform well by passing the filtering, paging, and sorting parameters to nHibernate.  This can be done [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6765743/265877) with IQueryable.  However,
[according to Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/nhibernate-binding.aspx), nHibernate linq provider doesn't understand the `group by` query the mvc grid generates.

Their example is more than a year old, so I've just updated the sample project they provide to MVC3, nHibernate 3.2, and Telerik Extensions 2011.3.1115 and the sample project throws an error when I drag a column into the "Group By" space.  I'm guessing the problem is still there.

Is there a way to get this to work, or nothing can be done until nHibernate supports the `group by` syntax that the Telerik Grid is generating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Workaround solution

I got grouping to work with custom binding.  There is a helper library called [TelerikMvcGridCustomBindingHelper](https://bitbucket.org/Lunadie/telerikmvcgridcustombindinghelper/wiki/Home) that can make this a piece of cake.  I like the custom approach a lot since it allows for easy interception of data exchanged between the grid and the ORM.  I recommend you give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it automatically like with an IQueryable, however, you can do it manually by using custom binding. Take a look at the demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/custombinding). Basically your controller action will get a command class as an argument that will list your Filter, Group, Sort, and Paging info. You will then need to use this information to build up your query.

Comment: Thanks, I was coming to the same conclusion.  Can we suggest this to the nHibernate team to support in a future release?

Comment: Hmm according to https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2118 it should be fixed in 3.2GA. Perhaps it might be worthwhile submitting a failed test.